# How to combine 2 lists into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have 2 lists below:

```
a = ['ymd', 'publisher_name', 'country_name', 'ymd', 'publisher_name', 'country_name', 'ymd', 'publisher_name', 'country_name']
b = ['2022-12-01',  'Media1', 'United Kingdom', '2022-12-01',  'Media1', 'Brazil','2022-12-01', 'Media1', 'Laos']
```

when I tried to use zip and dict the result is this:

```
zip(a,b)
dictList=dict(zip(a,b))
print (dictList)
```

#results (only the last list is printed)

```
{'ymd': '2022-12-01', 'publisher_name': 'Media1', 'country_name': 'Laos'}
```

#desired results

```
{'ymd': '2022-12-01', 'publisher_name': 'Media1', 'country_name': 'United Kingdom'},
{'ymd': '2022-12-01', 'publisher_name': 'Media1', 'country_name': 'Brazil'},
{'ymd': '2022-12-01', 'publisher_name': 'Media1', 'country_name': 'Laos'}
```

Comment: You need to somehow tell Python that it has to split into 3 different dicts. Right now you are creating a single dictionary, and because a dict can not contain duplicate keys, you are seeing only the last values.

Comment: Your approach for the conversion is correct, the question should be how to split a list into groups of 3 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want multiple dictionaries so let's put them in a list as follows:

```
a = ['ymd', 'publisher_name', 'country_name', 'ymd', 'publisher_name', 'country_name', 'ymd', 'publisher_name', 'country_name']
b = ['2022-12-01',  'Media1', 'United Kingdom', '2022-12-01',  'Media1', 'Brazil','2022-12-01', 'Media1', 'Laos']

result = [dict()]

for k, v in zip(a, b):
    if len(result[-1]) == 3:
        result.append(dict())
    result[-1][k] = v


print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'ymd': '2022-12-01', 'publisher_name': 'Media1', 'country_name': 'United Kingdom'}, {'ymd': '2022-12-01', 'publisher_name': 'Media1', 'country_name': 'Brazil'}, {'ymd': '2022-12-01', 'publisher_name': 'Media1', 'country_name': 'Laos'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this example it will going to work and  combine 2 lists into a dictionary

```
final_list = [{a:b for a,b in zip(a[i:i+3], b[i:i+3])} for i in range(0, len(a), 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

you have almost got it but you need to pass pieces of length 3 into the function

```py
def solve(a,b) :
    zip(a,b)
    dictList=dict(zip(a,b))
    print (dictList)
    
a = ['ymd', 'publisher_name', 'country_name', 'ymd', 'publisher_name', 'country_name', 'ymd', 'publisher_name', 'country_name']
b = ['2022-12-01',  'Media1', 'United Kingdom', '2022-12-01',  'Media1', 'Brazil','2022-12-01', 'Media1', 'Laos']

for i in range(0, len(a), 3):
    solve(a[i:i+3], b[i:i+3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapt [this recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/312644/567595) to divide the zipped lists into chunks, then turn that into a list of dicts.

```
result = [dict(chunk) for chunk in zip(*[zip(a, b)] * 3)]
```